# The array/loop complies correctly, however how do you keep a part of the output the same?

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse, loops

Perhaps i wasn't clear enough. I apologize. I tried condensing and adding images in this edit to make it more clear.

[50 Seed Value, 1200 RNG Value.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mGU4T.png)

[60 Seed Value, 1200 RNG Value.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SAXkz.png)

In the examples above (for clarity instead of writing it all out), you can see the outputs you get for 50 vs 60. It's not the distinct values I'm concerned. It's the display now. As you can see, the number gets bigger since I put in a new seed value. I want it to display what the 50 seed value is, but have the properties of whatever seed value I put in.

If I put in for example 60, I want to get:

H1 T1 H1 T1 HHH3 TTTTT5 H1 T1 HHHH4 T1 HH2 T1 H1 T1 H1 T1 H1 T1 H1 TTT3 H1 TTT3 H1 TTTT4 H1 T1 HHH3 TT2 H1 T... (just like with the 50 seed value).

BUT it would get 35 distinct values instead of the 30. Let me know if I can be clearer I apologize for being so confusing.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class CoinFlipAnalyzer{

     private static final Scanner     
     stdIn = new Scanner(System.in);

     public static void main (String[] args){


         // Integer Values:

         int totalNumberOfRuns = 0;
         int run = 1;


         // Boolean Values:


         boolean theCoin;
         boolean tempVal = false;


         // Gathering the Users Input:


         System.out.println("Welcome to the coin flip analyzer.\n"
         + "How many flips?");
         int numberOfFlips = stdIn.nextInt();
         System.out.println("What do you want to seed the random number generator with?");        
         int rngSeed = stdIn.nextInt();

         Random rng = new Random(rngSeed); // Initiates the Random Number Generator.              

         System.out.println();

         // Loop and Array to Decide Whether the Value is Heads or Tail.  

         long[] runLength = new long[numberOfFlips];        
              for (int i = 0; i < numberOfFlips; i++) {
                  theCoin = rng.nextBoolean(); // As requested, I used the nextBoolean expression.
                  if (theCoin != tempVal) {
                     if (i > 0) {
                        System.out.print(run + " ");
                     }
                        runLength[run - 1]++;               
                        totalNumberOfRuns++;
                        run = 1;
                     } 
                      else {
                         run++;
                     }
                      if (theCoin) {           
                          System.out.print("H");
                          tempVal = true;
                     }
                      else {
                          System.out.print("T");
                          tempVal = false;                          
                      }                            
                 }         
          System.out.print("...");         
          System.out.println();

          System.out.println("There were a total of " + totalNumberOfRuns + 
              " distinct runs in the simulation.\nTheir breakdown follows:");
          System.out.println();
```

Comment: I don't follow. You have 50 flips and then 60 flips. Why is the output going to be the same?

Comment: @KevinO what I mean is that you'll get different outputs, but it will display simply the: 
H1 T1 H1 T1 HHH3 TTTTT5 H1 T1 HHHH4 T1 HH2 T1 H1 T1 H1 T1 H1 T1 H1 TTT3 H1 TTT3 H1 TTTT4 H1 T1 HHH3 TT2 H1 T...
Every single time to reduce clutter. It will still give different results based off my seed values. It's a visual preference if you'd like to think of it like that.

Comment: @KevinO Feel free to read the top post with the code in it again. If it's still not clear, let me know.

Comment: This question still seems incomprehensible to me. Are you just trying to change how the output is formatted? What kind of "overflow" are you observing? I suspect the `textwrap` module would probably solve your problem but I'm still not completely sure what makes your "good" output better than your "bad" output. And if you only care about the output, you can cut out a lot of your example code and just focus on the part that prints the output.

Comment: @DanielPryden it may be a text wrap fix. I've supplied some images in the update I just did. I've condensed my code, and simplified my wording a little bit. I'm not concerned with the outputs. THOSE are correct. I WANT 30 distinct values when I input 50 as a seed. I WANT 35 when I input 60 as a seed, but what I need, is for it to do that process all while only displaying up until the "T..." because as the number gets longer, so do the distinct values. Let me know if I can clarify more. I apologize for being confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I understand the requirement. In essence, there is some desired width, and if the number of outputs exceeds the width, then print using an ellipses.

There is the [StringUtils from Apache Commons](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html) that has an 'Abbreviate' method.

> `public static String abbreviate(String str,
>                                   int maxWidth)`
>
> Abbreviates a String using ellipses. This will turn "Now is the time for all good men" into "Now is the time for..."

To use this (or the other suggestion below), I would remove the immediate output that is being generated in the run, and instead build a `String`. One could build a `char[]` as well, but here we will go with a `String` (or a `StringBuilder`). There is another advantage to so doing -- it is generally a good practice to separate some of the logic from the output. Plus it would be more testable.

So, if one can use the `StringUtils.abbreviate(...)`, then take the result from the `doFlips(...)` and pass it to the method, and the result will be done.

```
/*
 * moved the flipping into a method; allow it to build the
 *  results rather than immediately outputting them
*/
private static StringBuilder doFlips(int numberOfFlips, Random rng)
{
    long[] runLength = new long[numberOfFlips];
    boolean theCoin;
    boolean tempVal = false;

    int run = 1;
    int totalNumberOfRuns = 0;

    // Here we will collect the output; use better name in production
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfFlips; i++) {
        theCoin = rng.nextBoolean(); // As requested, I used the nextBoolean
                                     // expression.
        if (theCoin != tempVal) {
            if (i > 0) {
                sb.append(run);
                sb.append(" ");
            }
            runLength[run - 1]++;
            totalNumberOfRuns++;
            run = 1;
        }
        else {
            run++;
        }
        if (theCoin) {
            sb.append("H");
            tempVal = true;
        }
        else {
            sb.append("T");
            tempVal = false;
        }
    }

    return sb;
}
```

If one cannot use the library, it is easy enough to write a `chop` method:

```
/**
 * Chop the input StringBuilder and give "..." at
 * maxOutput.
 * 
 * NOTE: no error checking
 */
private static String ourChop(StringBuilder sb, int maxOutput)
{
    if (sb.length() <= maxOutput) {
        return sb.toString();
    }

    // we chop everything past maxOutput - 3
    sb.setLength(maxOutput - 3);
    sb.append("...");

    return sb.toString();
}
```

So, we can then do the following:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int seed = 1200;
    int maxOutput = 25;

    // 50 flips, 25 length max, including ... if needed
    StringBuilder res = doFlips(50, new Random(seed));
    System.out.println(ourChop(res, maxOutput));

    res = doFlips(60, new Random(seed));
    System.out.println(ourChop(res, maxOutput));
```

And we get this output (at 25):

```
H1 T1 H1 T1 HHH3 TTTTT...
H1 T1 H1 T1 HHH3 TTTTT...
```

Now, if the goal is to align to the max output of some given run, then one would need to collect all of the runs (50, 60, etc.), and then find the particular value (say the shortest of the outputs; note that in theory in a truly random setting, 60 could have a shorter output than 50, but not when using the same seed). One could then use that determined value to chop to a given output length.

If I have misunderstood the approach, I apologize.

Comment: @cos, I am glad it may have helped! I would appreciate it if you would consider accepting the answer :) Cheers!